# VS Code find-and-replace: is there a way to keep my previous find term when I type ctrl+h?

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace, find

Currently, when I use ctrl+h with something highlighted, my find term is set equal to the highlighted text. Is there a way to stop that (and keep my find term the same as it was previously)?

Often I want to find-and-replace in VS Code, do something, highlight something, and then find-and-replace the same thing again. Is there a way to make it so that I don't have to retype my find term a second time?

I know there are some plugins that have this functionality; if you know of any that allow me to see both my find and replace terms at the same time, I would like to know.

Comment: you can use the up-down-Arrow keys

Comment: Thanks! I will upvote your comment once I'm allowed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this setting to `false`:

> // Controls if we seed the search string in Find Widget from editor selection
>
> "editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection": false,

`Editor > Find: Seed Search String From Selection`

Doing this will also affect your Find/Search in Files functionality.